# Aligned TextInputLayout text to the right

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have a `EditText` within a `TextInputLayout`. The `EditText` text floats to the right. I want the TextInputLayout to follow suit. Using `android:gravity="right"` on the EditText the text aligns to the right, but this doesn't work on `TextInputLayout`.

Any advice how to get the `TextInputLayout` text to float to the right?

Answer (score -1):

This is not even possible when you have RTL support, and you select Arabic/Hebrew language.

The hint will float to left side instead of right side!

Comment: This is crazy. Thanks for the reply though.